# Alternative for if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

What other alternatives for the `if` statement in the following code, are there?

```
$page_title = $titles['default'];
$page_desc  = $descriptions['default'];

if(array_key_exists($module, $titles) && !empty($titles[$module]))
{
    $page_title = $titles[$module];
}
if(array_key_exists($module, $descriptions) && !empty($descriptions[$module]))
{
    $page_desc  = $descriptions[$module];
}
```

The above code works great, I'm just looking to see if there's any room of improvement.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? If you want a suggestion, place the first curly bracket on the same line :P

Comment: What do you mean by "improving"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? ;)

```
($page_title = @$titles[$module]) or $page_title = $titles['default'];
($page_desc = @$descriptions[$module]) or $page_desc = $descriptions['default'];
```

or this?

```
$page_title = @$titles[$module] ?: $titles['default'];
$page_desc = @$descriptions[$module] ?: $descriptions['default'];
```

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware you could skip out the secondary param. nice.

Comment: @pebbl: It has been added since PHP 5.3

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the info! :) it's always been something of an annoyance that you couldn't do this before... especially when the first check was a complex route to an attribute or something that you would have to repeat in the second part.

Answer (score 4):

```
$page_title = isset($titles[$module]) ? $titles[$module] : $titles['default'];
$page_desc  = isset($descriptions[$module]) ? $descriptions[$module] : $descriptions['default'];
```

Comment: `isset` doesn't check if the value is empty

Comment: @maggie is right, just remembered that

Comment: Does not indeed. But can be replaced by mere `empty` as `empty` does not trigger notice for undefined indexes

Comment: I don't know how it is an improved version. Its just shorthand. Improvisation means changing the core.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different way :) - I make no statement to say it is better... it depends on the situation.

```
$titles += array("$module" => $titles['default']);
$descriptions += array("$module" => $descriptions['default']);

$page_title = $titles[$module];
$page_desc = $descriptions[$module];
```